# I need a button that will scroll 400px down every time it's clicked

Tags: button, scroll, keyboard-shortcuts, smooth-scrolling

I have an image that I will use as the button. I need some code that will make the page scroll smoothly down 400px every time the image is clicked.

I think JQuery or Javascript would do the trick, I am not really sure because I do not know them.

It would be even better in fact, if instead of button, I could just have a keyboard shortcut. Just like Google on Google+, "J" and "K" are used to move up and down the posts. This is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Every post in my site will be the same height so that might make it easier to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind an animate function to the click event of your image or button and let it animate the scrollTop property with 400.

For example, place this button on your page:

```
<input type="button" value="Scroll" id="scroll" />
```

And use this piece of JavaScript:

```
$('#scroll').click(function() {
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: +400}, 1000);
})
```

Just make sure jQuery is loaded and it will work.

Load jQuery by adding this just before the body end tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And the best way to include the JavaScript snippet is to place the following between the script rule above and the body end tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#scroll').click(function() {
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: +400}, 1000);
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Like I said, I don't know JQuery or Javascript, so how exactly do I make sure JQuery is loaded?

Just so we are on the same page, I have placed the button in the page body while the Javascript you provided inside the <head> tag. so far it's not working for me.

Comment: Wow, it works! thank you!
Only one tiny problem. it only works once. I even tried adding the button twice, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try replacing "{scrollTop: +400}" with "{scrollTop: '+=400'}", and make it cross-browser by replacing "$('body')" with " $('html, body')". Check out the live example I've created over there: http://jsfiddle.net/dely/TN4wP/14/.